# Automation Error: Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type

Tags: excel, vba, automation

My code is very simple yet gets the below error:

Automation Error: Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type

```
Sub jumptosummary()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am in a sheet with many tabs and was using this to simply get back to my Summary tab

Comment: Do you have any add-ins loaded?

Comment: could be the sheet is corrupted. If you can duplicate the data in a new sheet it will work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.